# Using makefiles and vim without prompt

Tags: vim, makefile

I'm using vim and im doing a lot of

```
:make
```

within vim. The only thing that is really annoying is that I have to press ENTER twice to jump back to the editor. I just want to go directly back if everything worked out fine. And I want to see the error once and press a key to jump directly to the error line.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why twice? It shows you the errors, you press ENTER once and it gets to the error! The only thing that may happen is if the output is bigger than 1 page and it lets you read the whole thing, in which case ENTER only moves it one line and space one page. In such a case, with ESC you can ignore the output of make. But either way, if too long and you press ESC, or short and you press ENTER, you only need to do it once.

Comment: You '... want to see the error once and press a key to jump directly to the error line'? I want to see no errors and execute the program: `make test | !./test` :)

Comment: I dont know why i have to hit it twice. What's intersting is that it `:!make` prompts just once.

Comment: That's because `!` runs the following command in the shell. That uses make directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is known as the [hit-enter prompt](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/message.html#hit-enter):

> If you accidentally hit  or  and you want to see the displayed
>   text then use |g<|.  This only works when 'more' is set.
>
> To reduce the number of hit-enter prompts:
>
> - Set 'cmdheight' to 2 or higher.
> - Add flags to 'shortmess'.
> - Reset 'showcmd' and/or 'ruler'.

Also, I'm sure you are aware of **[the quickfix window (`:copen`) to navigate errors/messages](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html)**?

Answer (score 3):

This can happen when the 'cmdheight' varible is < 2.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. This is a simple solution that seems to work:

```
map <F2> :silent make^M
```

Now I just hit the F2 key to compile and the annoying prompt is not so annoying.

Comment: Though on some terminals, weirdness happens. :-(
:help hit-enter says some things, but I can't figure out the optimal setup.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it would help you, but if you're on Windows you could try:

```
:set makeprg=start\ make
```

I think this will break the `errorfile` setting though.

See:

- `:help make`
- `:help !start`